# Applying SAX or DOM to Xml using SOAP in android?

Tags: android

I need some help regarding SOAP services in android.I have been working on parsing xml data created using Php.However i am totally new to parse xml created using .net services.I am using Soap Library.Were we get data (xml) as a string.My question is can i apply SAX or DOM parser on the response that i get here in soap services?Can some one please give me some Links for Tutorials on soapservices and parse the data/Fetch the data from the webservice.Or whether i need to use substring  to fetch the data?
This is part of my xml file:
I will be having multiple tags of .

```
<DataSet>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true"><xs:complexType><xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"><xs:element name="ProfileData">
.
.
.
.
.
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
<diffgr:diffgram>
<NewDataSet>
<ProfileData diffgr:id="ProfileData1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<ProfileID>170</ProfileID>
<MerchantID>59</MerchantID>
</ProfileData>
<IPhoneData diffgr:id="IPhoneData1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
<Value>38813</Value>
<Amount>-0.02</Amount>
<ApprovalCode/>
<Status>a</Status>
<DueDate>2013-02-18T09:36:00.133-05:00</DueDate><InsertedOn>2013-02-19T04:27:39.03-05:00</InsertedOn>
<Type>2</Type>
</IPhoneData>
<IPhoneData diffgr:id="IPhoneData2" msdata:rowOrder="2">
<Value>38813</Value>
<Amount>-0.02</Amount>
<ApprovalCode/>
<Status>a</Status>
<DueDate>2013-02-18T09:36:00.133-05:00</DueDate><InsertedOn>2013-02-19T04:27:39.03-05:00</InsertedOn>
<Type>2</Type>
</IPhoneData>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you are reading the data, hence you should be using SAX parser only. DOM is generally used to read/ write XML file. See the diff. over [here](http://allu.wordpress.com/2006/12/28/difference-between-sax-and-dom-parsers/).

You can find more information [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/parsers/SAXParser.html).

Comment: ,can u please guide me on how to parse the xml.Because uisng    SoapObject result_body = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;
   System.out.println(result.toString());
   Log.e( "we service result = ","" + result_body); returns a string.How can i apply sax parser then on it?

Comment: well it would be spoon feeding. Read the concept, get the sample by searching from Google. i.e. - http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-xml-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: Hey Rajni thnx for the tutorial all i need help is i get the string (in soap response)here and not the xml file in tags.Then how can i apply SAX parser.

Comment: saxParser.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(yourString))), handler); replace values of yourString variable.